# Where to find complete list of iOS app permissions?

Tags: ios, ios-permissions

Where to find complete list of iOS app permissions?

For android you may find a complete list of normal and dangerous permissions, which apps could use: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html

Of course I know the "dangerous" permissions of iOS, they are displayed in settings>privacy. But Im also interested in the normal settings which can not be influenced by user.

I think for developers there should be a list like that for android. Or ist the system working completely another way? So where could I learn about this?

Why am I asking? For my degree Im researching whether users now which data is collected in smart mobile devices. Therefore I need a reference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Complete list of iOS app permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29894749/complete-list-of-ios-app-permissions)

Answer (score 0):

This may be useful:
https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf

Relevant post:
[Complete list of iOS app permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29894749/complete-list-of-ios-app-permissions)

The info.plist is where you can add keys for permissions when writing your iOS app. Here's the documentation for that:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Introduction/Introduction.html