# iOS network access permissions in China

Tags: ios, networking, user-permissions

I recently got feedback from a user who said that my app's network functionality was broken in China, since I didn't show the permission dialog to users.

Apple's [list of permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29894749/complete-list-of-ios-app-permissions) doesn't include it - does it exist?

[Here's an article about this issue](https://sspai.com/post/35720) (in Chinese; translated [here](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=zh-CN&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fsspai.com%2Fpost%2F35720&edit-text=)).

[image: Network permissions?]

Comment: what's the alert asking for? IDK Chinese. The problem may arise due to the sever endpoint you called from app is blocked by Chinese network

Comment: Does changing the region on device helps to tackle this issue? Just a thought

Comment: @Vinaykrishnan unable to verify but I guess this feature would be impossible to bypass with user settings - perhaps it's enforced on all devices sold in China.. cannot tell for sure.

Answer (score -1):

As @Tomas Andrle said, this "feature" is only show in devices sold in China(Mainland).
Just ignore it, and add something like retry button when network is useless.