# Xamarin.Forms iOS Add Contact (via Dependency Service)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin.Forms App where I like to open the Add Contact Screen. I used the Depedency Service to do this. It works fine on Android but every time I run it on my iPhone, it crashes.
My sample code is below.

```
public bool SaveContactAsync(Profile ContactToSave)
        {
            var store = new CNContactStore();
            var contact = new CNMutableContact();
            var cellPhone = new CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber>(CNLabelPhoneNumberKey.Mobile, new CNPhoneNumber(ContactToSave.PhoneNumber));
            var phoneNumber = new[] { cellPhone };
            contact.PhoneNumbers = phoneNumber;
            contact.GivenName = ContactToSave.FirstName;
            contact.FamilyName = ContactToSave.LastName;
            var emailAddress = new CNLabeledValue<NSString>(CNLabelKey.Other, new NSString(ContactToSave.EmailAddress));
            contact.EmailAddresses = new CNLabeledValue<NSString>[] { emailAddress };
            var saveRequest = new CNSaveRequest();
            saveRequest.AddContact(contact, store.DefaultContainerIdentifier);

            NSError error;
            if (store.ExecuteSaveRequest(saveRequest, out error))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
```

The application crashes once it get to  `saveRequest.AddContact(contact, store.DefaultContainerIdentifier);`. What could I be doing wrong?
I looked at the App Center Diagnostics, here's what I saw.

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib
__abort_with_payload
libsystem_kernel.dylib
abort_with_payload
TCC
__CRASHING_DUE_TO_PRIVACY_VIOLATION__
TCC
__TCCAccessRequest_block_invoke.124
TCC
__tccd_send_message_block_invoke
libxpc.dylib
_xpc_connection_reply_callout
libxpc.dylib
_xpc_connection_call_reply_async
libdispatch.dylib
_dispatch_client_callout3
libdispatch.dylib
_dispatch_mach_msg_async_reply_invoke$VARIANT$mp
libdispatch.dylib
_dispatch_kevent_worker_thread
libsystem_pthread.dylib
_pthread_wqthread
libsystem_pthread.dylib
start_wqthread
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **CRASHING_DUE_TO_PRIVACY_VIOLATION**

It seems that you didn't add the Contact permission to your app .

Add the following code to the info.plist in iOS project.

```
<key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>  
<string>Your app needs access your Contact</string>
```

And in **Depedency Service**

```
   public bool CheckPermission()
    {

        CNAuthorizationStatus status = CNContactStore.GetAuthorizationStatus(CNEntityType.Contacts);

        if(status==CNAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined)
        {
            // need request permission
            CNContactStore store = new CNContactStore();
            store.RequestAccess(CNEntityType.Contacts,null);

        }
        else if(status == CNAuthorizationStatus.Restricted|| status == CNAuthorizationStatus.Denied)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("user restricted the permission");
        }

        else if(status==CNAuthorizationStatus.Authorized)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

```
var hasPermission = CheckPermission();
if(hasPermission)
{
   SaveContactAsync(profile);
}
```

For more details about iOS permission you could check [Complete list of iOS app permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29894749/complete-list-of-ios-app-permissions)

Comment: Thank you Lucas, I did that, now I get a new kind of error.
SIGABRT: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: completionHandler
I'm guessing it's coming from 
store.RequestAccess(CNEntityType.Contacts,null);

Comment: Got it working now.
I changed store.RequestAccess(CNEntityType.Contacts,null); to store.RequestAccessAsync(CNEntityType.Contacts);